# navigation item not showing on first time

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

I am using navigation controller for each tab, and the first controller in each tab not showing any item in the navigation, but if I click on cell and return back the items on the navigation shows normally.

Why?

Thanks,

Comment: Please share some code about how and when you set up the barButtonItems

Comment: Can you give more details ? Your question is not clear. I suppose you have a TableView or CollectionView if you tap on cell...

Comment: In iOS 11 the navigationBar started using autolayouts for all the subviews, you should set the frame of your views as constraints. If you can provide more detail in what you are trying to add we might be able to provide more help.